# Computing the gradient of scalar wrt a vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let 
$$
\alpha = x^TAx \enspace x\in \mathbf{R}^{nx1}, A \in \mathbf{R}^{nxn}
$$

How do I compute the derivative $\Large \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}$
without using the coordinate way i.e, writing A in terms of $\large A = (a_{ij})$

My attempt is as follows (using the product rule):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x} = &\frac{\partial(x^TAx)}{\partial x}\\
=&\frac{\partial(x^TA)x}{\partial x} + x^TA\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\\
=&\frac{\partial(A^Tx)^Tx}{\partial x} + x^TAI\\
=&\left(\frac{\partial A^Tx}{\partial x}\right)^Tx+ x^TA\\
=&Ax+x^TA
\end{align}
$$

This is different from the answer that I find in wikipedia which says is to be:

$$
\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x} = x^TA+x^TA^T
$$

Where am I going wrong, please present your answer in the product rule form.

Comment: (1) What exactly is the definition of $\partial\alpha/\partial x$ that you're using? This notation is not very common.  (2) In the last line of your attempted answer, you're adding a column vector $Ax$ and a row vector $x^TA$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: (1) This is used in the derivation of Kalman Filter, the equations are something quite similar. So, I simplified the equations
(2) Yes, how do I ensure that the answer is right?, What changes am I supposed to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product rule is not valid for the gradients of matrix/vector expressions.

For example
$$\frac{\partial(a^Tb)}{\partial x} \ne \Bigg(\frac{\partial a^T}{\partial x}\Bigg)b + a^T\Bigg(\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\Bigg)$$
However, the product rule is valid for the differentials of such expressions
$$d(a^Tb) = (da^T)b + a^T(db)$$

Note that the gradient of a vector is a matrix, which behaves differently than a vector. 

But the differential of a vector is just another vector, and behaves accordingly.

So let's approach your problem using differentials.
$$\eqalign{
 \alpha &= x^TAx \cr
d\alpha
 &= dx^T\,Ax + x^TA\,dx \cr
 &= x^TA^T\,dx + x^TA\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} &= x^TA^T + x^TA \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: I didn't know of the `product rule` for vector derivaties. Thanks for that. Could you please give me some resources on matrix calculus?

Comment: Some matrix calculus resources:  
This site is a pretty good resource, just start exploring.  
If you want books, then Magnus & Neudecker is good; Are Hjorungnes' book is good, too.

Answer (score 0):

WE can write $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}$ in form of a **row vector** as:
$$
\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}=x^T(A+A^T)
$$
as you find in Wikipedia, or as a **column vector** 
$$
\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}=(A+A^T)x
$$
as you can see [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) at pag 11.

In your result you have the addition of a row with a column vector that is not possibile. Changing one of the two you find one of the two forms.